# Neo4j REST batch Illegal character in path at index 2: ./{0}/properties/

Tags: neo4j

The Request:

```
[{
    "method": "GET",
    "to": "/node/1890",
    "id": 0
  },
 {
    "method": "PUT",
    "to": "{0}/properties/Name",
    "body": "NewName",
    "id": 1
}]
```

The Response:

```
{
    "message": "Illegal character in path at index 2: ./{0}/properties/Name",
    "exception": "IllegalArgumentException",
    "fullname": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException",
    "stacktrace": ["java.net.URI.create(URI.java:859)", "java.net.URI.resolve(URI.java:1043)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.BatchOperations.calculateTargetUri(BatchOperations.java:100)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.BatchOperations.performRequest(BatchOperations.java:181)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.BatchOperations.parseAndPerform(BatchOperations.java:159)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.NonStreamingBatchOperations.performBatchJobs(NonStreamingBatchOperations.java:48)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.BatchOperationService.batchProcess(BatchOperationService.java:117)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.BatchOperationService.performBatchOperations(BatchOperationService.java:72)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)"],
    "cause": {
        "message": "Illegal character in path at index 2: ./{0}/properties/Name",
        "exception": "URISyntaxException",
        "stacktrace": ["java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)", "java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3002)", "java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3086)", "java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3044)", "java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:595)", "java.net.URI.create(URI.java:857)", "java.net.URI.resolve(URI.java:1043)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.BatchOperations.calculateTargetUri(BatchOperations.java:100)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.BatchOperations.performRequest(BatchOperations.java:181)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.BatchOperations.parseAndPerform(BatchOperations.java:159)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.NonStreamingBatchOperations.performBatchJobs(NonStreamingBatchOperations.java:48)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.BatchOperationService.batchProcess(BatchOperationService.java:117)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.BatchOperationService.performBatchOperations(BatchOperationService.java:72)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)"],
        "fullname": "java.net.URISyntaxException"
    }
}
```

What's the problem here?
No errors in messages.log or any other logs for that matter.  Not sure why the logs are empty. I had to turn off the X-Stream header to get this much info.

Now I know that since I already know the node's ID I can just reference it directly, and I will.  However, it seems like it is an issue that should work.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the URL for the 2nd request should be

```
/node/{0}/properties/foo
```

Comment: Doesn't work - "message": "Illegal character in path at index 7: ./node/{0}/properties/Name",